# Angular 5 push node on selection in a subject

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, publish-subscribe, subject

I am trying to implement functionality which does the following:

When nodes are selected from the TreeNode hierarchy on the left, they are displayed in the order of selection on the right. I was able to achieve this using EventEmitters but now I am trying to figure out a simpler/cleaner way to do it.

checkbox-tree.component.ts:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { TreeNode } from './../../dto/TreeNode';
import { BaseTreeComponent } from './../base-tree/base-tree.component';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

import html from './checkbox-tree.component.html';
import css from '../fortune-select.component.css';

@Component({
  selector: 'checkbox-tree',
  template: html,
  styles: [css],
})

export class CheckboxTreeComponent<T> extends BaseTreeComponent<T> {
  rightSideSubject                  = new Subject<TreeNode<T>[]>();
  selections: TreeNode<T>[] = [];

  //gets called when a node is selected
  public selected():void {
    if(!this.linked || (this.currentNode.indeterminate && !this.currentNode.selected)) {
      this.dataChangedEvent();
      return;
    }

    this.currentNode.indeterminate = false;
    if(this.singleLevelOnly) {
      this.currentNode.selectChildrenSingleLevel(this.currentNode.selected);
    } else {
      this.currentNode.selectChildren(this.currentNode.selected);
    }

    this.selections.push(this.currentNode);
    this.rightSideSubject.next(this.selections);
    this.childChanged.emit();
    this.dataChangedEvent();
  }

}
```

In this function, "currentNode" has the value of the current node which has been selected.
I want to maintain a list which has all the nodes in the order of selection. I want to push the node in the subject whenever it is selected. How do I do that? The current node needs to be pushed in the subject.

In the other component, I can get the rightSideSubject as an input and display!

How do I pass this data and push it in the rightSideSubject when selected?

Answer (score 0):

For me the "base" of this kind of component is to be "reusable" in any context.

To do so it must be usable with "ngModel", the model can contain simple value or array (for your case) and you can easily check the value with (ngModelChange). That is simple and standardized.

It may be a bit hard to understand at the beginning but you and your team will gain in knowledge and it will also work with "formControlName", which can be used in some situations.

You can find a good example here https://medium.com/@tarik.nzl/angular-2-custom-form-control-with-validation-json-input-2b4cf9bc2d73

Here are some easy final codes of my own: https://github.com/xrobert35/asi-ngtools/blob/master/src/components/asi-switch/asi-switch. component.ts https://github.com/xrobert35/asi-ngtools/blob/master/src/components/common/default-control-value-accessor.ts

Note, that there is a lot as "simple" compoment in this repository working with [ngModel] from where you can take "example", each component extends the class DefaultControlValueAccessor causes it to each component repeat the same "pattern"

this one work with array value : https://github.com/xrobert35/asi-ngtools/blob/master/src/components/asi-autocomplete/multiple/asi-autocomplete-multiple.component.ts